# Grails: Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY when writing

Tags: json, grails, grails3

I'm trying to parse a JSON object using grails.converters.JSON, but this errors appears.

The code

```
def str  = '{"a": "b"}'
def json = new JSON(str)
```

or

```
def map = [:]
map.a = "b"
def json = map as JSON
json = new JSON(json.toString())
```

are returning this following error:

```
2016-11-22 14:21:34.592 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : JSONException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/index
Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY when writing '{"a":"b"}' but was INIT. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: org.grails.web.json.JSONException: Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY when writing '{"a":"b"}' but was INIT
    at org.grails.web.converters.AbstractConverter.toString(AbstractConverter.java:111)
    at grails3.TestController$$EQ3IkyX7.index(TestController.groovy:25)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: org.grails.web.json.JSONException: Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY when writing '{"a":"b"}' but was INIT
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:193)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:119)
    at org.grails.web.converters.AbstractConverter.toString(AbstractConverter.java:109)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.web.json.JSONException: Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY when writing '{"a":"b"}' but was INIT
    at org.grails.web.json.JSONWriter.append(JSONWriter.java:142)
    at org.grails.web.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:353)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:162)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Grails version: 3.2.3
Java version: 1.8u45 and 1.8u111

Comment: Have you tried `def json = JSON.parse('{"a": "b"}')`?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Yep. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This statement itself converts the map to JSON.

```
def val = [a: 101, b: '100'] as JSON
```

You don't need the do this `json = new JSON(json.toString())` anymore

Comment: It is just an example. I did it to proof that I am trying to parse a valid json.

Comment: are you trying to fetch the json content from a request object on a controller by any chance?